# How can I convert this query result to date format (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This for example :

```
concat (concat('201', (substring('A41020', 2, 1)), '-', (substring('B210906', 6, 2))
```

and the result is 2014-06.

What additional query I can use to change this string (2014-06) to date format while I retrieve the data?

For now, I have to change cell format in Excel when I am using data from this query.

Help me master

Comment: Salam Muhammad.. please give more detail what you want to do exactly. what is 'A41020' and 'B210906'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query..here i have set the date as 01,which you can change as per your requirement. Also you can use CONVERT or CAST function in this situation.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'201'+substring('A41020', 2, 1)+'-'+substring('B210906', 6, 2)+'-01')
```

OR

```
SELECT CAST(('201'+substring('A41020', 2, 1)+'-'+substring('B210906', 6, 2)+'-01')as  datetime)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you master @Unnikrishnan R , this problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

If it's a table column that you want to convert:

```
  CONVERT(DATETIME,[Your-column])
```

If you want to convert the result of a select query:

```
  CONVERT(DATETIME,[select query])
```

When you try to convert the string to datetime, the string should have year,month and date or else you will need to append whichever is missing.

In your case, your result is `2014-06` which is missing the date part.If you try to convert this,it will give you a conversion error.
You can convert the above string by adding a date part.

```
select convert(datetime,'2014-06-01');
```

It will give the result as below:

[image: Output]

Comment: @jibinBalachardran I have try, but there are message in SQL server said that conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: @MuhammadDodySuhada, What's the string you are trying to convert as datetime?

Comment: @MuhammadDodySuhada Show me the output of that query

Comment: @MuhammadDodySuhada, I guess you are missing the datepart in your select result, append a date part and try to convert it.It should work. I have updated my answer, check it.

Comment: @jibinBalachardra, so, i missing the date part, in that case, if i add date part i can convert to a datetime?

Comment: @MuhammadDodySuhada Yes,you can.. Your current query is giving only month and year part. So append the date part and convert it

Comment: thank you master @jibinBalachardran , the problem is solved

Comment: @MuhammadDodySuhada In case it worked for you, you can give a +1. So that it will be useful for others as well